# The card is moving in vertical direction, as i am trying to get that in horizontal movement

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I am just trying to make an image move within specified canvas area. If the mouse cursor is moved out of the canvas area, the  image should get back to original position. below is the code i have tried.

```
  <mx:Script>
<![CDATA[
    import mx.controls.Image;
    import mx.containers.Canvas;
    import flash.geom.Rectangle;
     /* [Embed(source="cards/2C.png")]
     private var pic:Class; */
     public var points:Point;
     public var clan:Canvas;
     public var offset_x:int;
     public var offset_y:int;
     public var dropIndex:int=-1; 
     public var img:Image;
     public var dragImage:Image;
     public var myImage:Image;
     public var doDrag:Boolean;
     public var acceptDrag:Boolean;
     public function init():void

     {
        myImage = new Image();
        clan = new Canvas();
        clan.width=400;
        clan.height=300;
        clan.x=200;
        clan.y=150;
        clan.setStyle("backgroundColor",0xcfdccc);
        addChild(clan);
        myImage.source= pic.pic1;
        clan.addChild(myImage);
        myImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, ondown);
        myImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, mm); 

     }
     public function ondown(event:MouseEvent):void
     {
        doDrag=true;
        return;
     }
    public function mm(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if(doDrag==true)
        {

        points = new Point();
        myImage.source=event.target.source;
        points.x=event.target.x;
        points.y=event.target.y;
        points=localToGlobal(points);
        dragImage = mx.controls.Image(event.target);
        myImage.x=points.x;
        myImage.y=points.y;
        trace(points);
        var mywidth:int=clan.width-myImage.width;
        var myheight:int=clan.height-myImage.height;

        var boundar:flash.geom.Rectangle=new Rectangle(offset_x, offset_y ,mywidth,myheight);
        myImage.startDrag(false, boundar);
        myImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onmove);
        myImage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onup);
        event.updateAfterEvent();
        }

    }

    public function onmove(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if(doDrag)
        {

    //  myImage = new Image();
        clan = new Canvas();
        var diff:Number = NaN;
        var doIncrement:Boolean=false;
        var point2:flash.geom.Point= new Point();
        img=mx.controls.Image(event.target);

        point2.x=this.x;
        point2.y=this.y;
        point2=globalToLocal(point2);

        trace("point2="+ point2);
        diff=points.x; 
        /* trace(stage.x);
        trace(stage.y); */
        points.x=img.x;
        points.y=img.y;
        points=globalToLocal(points);
        diff=points.x;
        trace("points.x="+points.x);
        trace("diff: "+ diff);
        trace("dropIndex: "+ dropIndex);
        if(diff >=0)
        {
            dropIndex=Math.floor(points.x / offset_x);
            doIncrement=true;
            trace("dropIndex1: "+ dropIndex);

        }
        else
        {
            dropIndex=Math.floor(points.x / offset_x);

        }
         if(doIncrement)
        {
            dropIndex++;
        } 
         if(dropIndex >= 0)
        {
             acceptDrag = true;
        }

           else if (dropIndex >= -5 && dropIndex <= -1) 
                {
                    dropIndex = 0;
                    acceptDrag = true;
                }  
        }
    }
    public function onup(event:MouseEvent):void
    {

        doDrag=false;
        img.stopDrag();
        acceptDrag=false;
    }
        ]]>
      </mx:Script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, I believe you are making it much more complicated than it needs to be.  Adding a MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT event listener to the Canvas and then resetting the image to it's original coordinates should result in the behavior you are looking for.  Here is a quick and dirty version  I tested that you can use, expand on, or borrow from:

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private var offset_x:int;
        private var offset_y:int;

        /**
         * Calibrates the drag operation so that they ghosted image follows the cursor based on
         *     where the image was clicked.  It then makes the ghosted image visible and
         *     attaches the MOUSE_MOVE handler so that it will begin tracking.
         **/
        private function myImageMouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            offset_x = myImage.mouseX;
            offset_y = myImage.mouseY;
            dragImage.visible = true;

            clan.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onDrag);
        }

        /**
         * Calls the cleanup function then resets the ghosted image for further use.
         **/
        private function clanRolloutHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
            dragCleanup();

            dragImage.x = myImage.x;
            dragImage.y = myImage.y;
        }

        /**
         * Calls the cleanup function then sets the main Image to the ghosted image's location.
         **/
        private function endDrag(event:MouseEvent):void {
            dragCleanup();

            myImage.x = dragImage.x;
            myImage.y = dragImage.y;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the ghosted image to follow the mouse cursor offset by the location of the
         *     original click.
         **/
        private function onDrag(event:MouseEvent):void {
            dragImage.x = clan.mouseX - offset_x;
            dragImage.y = clan.mouseY - offset_y;
        }

        /**
         * Hides the ghosted image and removes the MOUSE_MOVE event handler so that the function
         *     is no longer called.
         **/
        private function dragCleanup():void {
            dragImage.visible = false;
            clan.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onDrag);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:Canvas id="clan" rollOut="clanRolloutHandler(event)" mouseUp="endDrag(event)" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
           top="150" left="200" width="400" height="300" backgroundColor="#CFDCCC">
    <mx:Image id="myImage" mouseDown="myImageMouseDownHandler(event)" 
              source="http://www.leadersinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/playing-cards.jpg" height="50" width="50"/>
    <mx:Image id="dragImage" alpha="0.5" visible="false" 
              source="http://www.leadersinstitute.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/playing-cards.jpg" height="50" width="50"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

Comment: You are a life savior. it sorted my half problem.

Answer (score 0):

MouseEvent.MOUSE_LEAVE will trigger when the mouse completely leaves the flash window, you could try resetting the images position when this happens and use MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTER to start tracking again, when required.

This should help: http://www.kirupa.com/developer/flashcs3/detecting_when_mouse_leaves_movie.htm

Comment: Thanks for looking at my problem, The answer given by Jeremy showed me the right direction to my problem.